# TextWatcher runs multiple times on entering Return Key in EditText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, textwatcher

I have a EditText with TextWatcher.

---

**Scenario 1:**

EditText containing "**abcd**"

If i press return key or enter newline

1) before the characters, `TextWatcher` fires 3 times.

2) in between the characters, `TextWatcher` fires 4 times.

3) at the end of the characters, `TextWatcher` fires 1 time.

---

**Scenario 2:**

EditText containing "**1234**"

If i press return key or enter newline

1) before the characters, `TextWatcher` fires 1 times.

2) in between the characters, `TextWatcher` fires 1 times.

3) at the end of the characters, `TextWatcher` fires 1 time.

---

Is this a bug?

Or is there any thing what i do not understand?

---

I want the text watcher to fire only once for all the scenario.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: can you post your on text change listener and text watcher code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution but may not be the perfect for all needs.

**Earlier**, when the `TextWatcher` was firing multiple times and code in it was also executed multiple times, I was with

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int count, int after) {

        Log.e(TAG, "111 text =---------------" + charSequence);
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int before, int count){

        Log.e(TAG, "222 text =---------------" + charSequence);
    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        Log.e(TAG, "333 text ---------------" + editable);
    }
});
```

Now, as per my requirements I found the solution and I am with

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    String initialText = "";
    private boolean ignore = true;

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int count, int after) {

        if ( initialText.length() < charSequence.length() ){

            initialText = charSequence.toString();
            Log.e(TAG, "111 text ---------------" + charSequence);
        }
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int before, int count){

        if( initialText.length() < charSequence.length() ) {

            initialText="";
            ignore=false;
            Log.e(TAG, "222 text ---------------" + charSequence);
        }
    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        if(!ignore) {

            ignore = true;
            Log.e(TAG, "333 text ---------------" + editable);
        }
    }
});
```

Now also the `TextWatcher` is **firing multiple times** but the code in the **if conditions are executed only once** for all the scenario that i mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the numbers are counted as single value i.e a number 1 or 12 "twelve" instead of 1,2. On the contrary when you enter words "Strings" they are divided into characters and the total count of character in the whole string is returned in the count parameter of textWatcher's overloaded methods.

e.g if you enter 123 it will be interpreted as a single value of one hundred and twenty three. Hence the count is returned as 1. And when you enter hello it is divided into individual characters i.e. 'h','e','l','l','o' which counts to total 5 characters. Hence the total count is returned as 5.

Hope this explanation helps.

Comment: In `TextWatcher` positioning is of usage then valuation. And Text watcher returns same positioning for **1234** and **abcd**. So does it also consider valuation?

Comment: in **Scenario 1** you can see all are Alphabets insted of numerics. So why there is such difference in firing the event?